# change x limits with percent scale in ggplot histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot histogram. I wish to set x-axis limit from 50% to 60%.

```
tbl <- tibble(x = runif(n = 100, min = 53, max = 58))

ggplot(tbl, 
       aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 50) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1, 
                                                     limits = c(50, 60)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your limits are not in the right place:

```
scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1), 
                     limits = c(50, 60))
```